# Виды присвоений значений переменным в python, в чем разница?

Tags: python, python-3.x, оператор-присваивания

```py
a, b = 5,7
a, b = b,a

print(a ,b) #7 5
```

Почему `b` не стало равно 7, если `a` уже равно 7?

Другой блок:

```py
a, b = 5, 7
a = b
b = a

print(a, b) #7 7
```

Comment: [Присвоение значений в Python. Различие способов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/614411)

Answer (score 1):

Код

```py
a, b = b, a
```

эквивалентен не такому коду:

```py
a = b
b = a
```

а такому:

```py
c = b
b = a
a = c
```

То есть переменные просто меняются местами: `a` становиться равным `b`, а `b` -  прошлому значению `a`.

---

А во втором примере вы сначала записываете в переменную `a` значение переменной `b`, а потом в `b` - то, что оказалось в `a`, т. е. тоже `b`.

```py
a = b
b = a
```

Answer (score 0):

В первом блоке кода, после замены a и b, значение a становится равным 7, а значение b становится равным 5. Это связано с тем, что замена переменных происходит одновременно, поэтому значение "b" сохраняется в "a" до того, как "a" присваивается "b"..

Во втором блоке кода, после установки a=5 и b=7, строка 'a=b' устанавливает значение a равным 7. Затем 'b=a' также устанавливает значение b равным 7. Таким образом, и a, и b становятся 7.